# Update record with clause IN

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm using Grails 4.0.12, and I'm trying to make an update using IN clause, this is my simple code:

```
def rowId="100,101"
Image.executeUpdate("update Image set status='DELETED' where status='NEW' and id in (:ids)", [ids: rowId])
```

If I build the query string like this, everything works:

```
 Image.executeUpdate("update Image set status='DELETED' where status='NEW' and id in ("+ids+")")
```

While in the fist example I'm getting this error:

**java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long**

Which seems reasonable if I pass just one Id without IN clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to correct your first example in the following way:

```
def rowIds = [100, 101]
Image.executeUpdate("update Image set status='DELETED' where status='NEW' and id in (:ids)", [ids: rowIds])
```